# How to start an app in the foreground?

Tags: macos, applications, terminal, applescript

For some reason, `gitk` always starts under all other apps.

How to make it start on top of all other apps, like a normal program?

Start it from the terminal with the `gitk` command, which lives in `/usr/bin`. There is no icon to click on...maybe need to create one?

Or is there a way to tell the OS to start it on top of all others? Perhaps with applescript?

Lion 10.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to edit the gitk file.

To find the location of your `gitk` file type the following

```
which gitk
```

Open the `gitk` file in a text editor, near the top you should see a line like the following

```
exec wish "$0" -- "$@"
```

Edit the line so that it looks like this

```
exec wish "$0" -- "$@" & exec osascript -e "tell application \"Wish\" to activate"
```

The next time you invoke `gitk` from the terminal it will come to the foreground

Your question is similar to a question on stackoverflow, if you don't want to edit the gitk file you can find other ways to achieve it there https://stackoverflow.com/q/11248284/1873471

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Thank you. Didn't think to look on StackOverflow. Live n' learn.

Comment: This works, but sometimes throws an error `27:35: execution error: An error of type -10827 has occurred. (-10827)`